# View and Reduce Storage for Azure Recovery Services

Tags: azure, backup

I got a large bill recently from Azure and see that Backup GRS Storage was a large chunk of that bill at 1.7TB. I see that the full VM backup had the retention period set to 180 days! So I changed it to 14. It doesn't appear as though this had an impact as the Recovery Services Vault overview page still shows Backup Storage for Cloud GRS is still at 1.7TB.

- How can I view the files in this vault?
- It doesn't appear as though this is linked to a separate Blob storage
  account...is this vault a separate type of storage account that
  doesn't use Blobs as the backing storage?
- Does reducing retention period days then delete any files older than that, hence freeing up that space? (Maybe I just need to wait a bit?...its been about 15 min with no reduction in storage.)

I did see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482236/microsoft-azure-backups-not-reducing-available-recovery-points-or-destination-us), but hoping after 5 years the answer is not that I need to create an entirely new vault!

Answer (score 0):

I have answered your query at - learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/98585/… Let me know if you have any other question in this regard